# Any difference between Chrome and Firefox web push - server side?

Tags: java, push-notification, web-push

I'm implementing the server side for web push using Java ... I was able to get the web push notification on Firefox. For the same code I added gcm api key header as Authorization: key=gcm_api_key . But it doesn't work for Chrome. I get a 201 response on posting the request. But message doesn't reach the chrome browser. No errors displayed anywhere.

What differences are there on the server side for web-push between client and server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With same code you can send to Chrome, Firefox and Opera latest versions. It depends how you have implemented it. Here is linked my project [browser push](https://lahiiru.github.io/browser-push)

Comment: This helps... Also fixed my code ... I used the salt that was url encoded initially. Firefox worked with that, but chrome didn't. The url encoding had to be done just before adding to the header... then worked for both.

Answer (score 0):

If you use GCM, there are a bunch of differences (GCM is a proprietary protocol).

FCM, instead, implements the [standard Web Push protocol](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-webpush-protocol-12), as the Firefox service ([Autopush](https://github.com/mozilla-services/autopush)) does.

In order to use FCM, you need to implement [VAPID](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-webpush-vapid-01).

Comment: You can also use FCM without VAPID. You can just [get the API key](https://pushpad.xyz/docs/certificates_and_keys) from the dashboard like you did in GCM.

Comment: Don't you need to use the `applicationServerKey` parameter when subscribing in order for Chrome to give you a FCM endpoint?

Comment: @collimarco Does it mean just adding the API key to the Authorization header will work? Everything else same as firefox sever side.

Comment: Currently for Pushpad we don't use VAPID and it works. We still use a `manifest.json` with a sender ID and an API key like we did for GCM - then just use `Authorization: key= your_api_key`. You can get the pair sender ID / API key from the Firebase dashboard.

Comment: What do the URLs of the endpoints look like? Do they start with `https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send`? Are you using push payloads?